# Metadata Subscription List not reflected in Project Metadata in MavensMate

Tags: metadata, mavensmate, refresh

I have MavensMate app v0.0.10 connected to my sandbox.

I create a project and get the default subscription to 6 metadata types.

Now I want more metadata types.

In the Advanced tab I have selected all the additional metadata types.  I clicked Update Subscription under the dropdown and received message Subscription updated.

Then I went to Project Metadata tab and clicked Refresh in the tab header.  No additional boxes get ticked.

I clicked Update Project at top right and then clicked Refresh again but no change.

If I close MavensMate and reopen it, the Metadata subscription list shows my updated list, 42 out of 69, but the Project Metadata still only has 6 boxes ticked.

- Why arent't the additional metadata types being ticked in the Project Metadata tab?

Thanks,
Mike.

Comment: Subscribing to the metadata types is different than selecting them to be in your local project. You need to tick what you want. IE I subscribe to custom object, now I need to select which custom objects to track (or all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jesse says, the Project Metadata boxes need to be ticked manually.